# Snapshot like macro for entire beamer frame?

Tags: beamer

I'm wondering if there is some macro I can use to take a snapshot of an entire Beamer frame (in its last slide) and reuse it in another frame. The following code does not work, is just for illustrating the idea.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\mymacro{
%normal frame content goes here
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\insertmymacro[scale=.30] %this will insert the snapshot of the previous frame, possibly scaled 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There should also be a way to tell the macro which frame has to be inserted if more than one has been snapshotted.

Does something like this already exist?

Comment: `\againframe[myframelabel]` where you have named a particular frame `myframelabel` Welcome to TeX.SX! ;-)

Comment: Do you want to provide a smaller 'snapshot' or the complete frame again?

Comment: a smaller snapshot, like when you put a snapshot of a web page into a book to illustrate its content. So I can't use `\againframe`

Comment: You want to show the frame content only again or the whole frame with borders etc?

Comment: the complete frame (scaled of course). Exaclty as if I took a real snapshot with a screen capture software and included it via `\includegraphics`

Comment: You might also try a \savebox.

Comment: The easiest way might just be to use a script to extract the relevant page and then include it on the next run. `pdftk` could easily extract the page and I imagine there is some equivalent for Windows. (But my imagination is, admittedly, ill informed on this point.)

Answer (score 7):

Here, I save the first frame in a named `\vbox`.  I can then recall the content (as is, or scaled and framed) with a `\usebox`.

I had to horizontally pad out the saved box a little; I think the padding is needed because the `\vbox` is of width `\textwidth` whereas the slide width is wider than that.

EDITED to remove stray blank frame.

MANUAL VERSION:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newsavebox\saveframe
\fboxsep=0pt
\begin{document}
%SAVE-FRAME
\savebox{\saveframe}{\vbox{
\begin{frame}
{1st Frame}
frame text from the first frame.  I will now begin an itemized list.  And we begin:
\begin{itemize}
\item AAA
\item BBB
\item CCC
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}}}

%PRESENT THE SAVE-FRAME AS IS
\begin{frame}
\usebox{\saveframe}
\end{frame}

%PRESENT THE 2ND FRAME INCLUDING A SCALED SAVE-FRAME
\begin{frame}
{2nd frame}
Here is my prior frame\par
\fbox{\scalebox{.6}{\hspace{1cm}\usebox{\saveframe}\hspace{1cm}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

AUTOMATED VERSION:

If one would like the boxing automated, I provide the `sframe{}` environment in the following MWE to output and save a frame.  A `{title}` is a mandatory argument to the environment.  A boxed, scaled version of the saved frame can be obtained with `\savedframe{scale}`, invoked inside a `frame` environment.  The following MWE behaves identically to the manual version above.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\global\newsavebox\thesaveframe

\newenvironment{sframe}[1]%
{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\begin{frame}{#1}}
{\end{frame}\leavevmode\unskip\setbox0=\lastbox \egroup%
 \global\sbox{\thesaveframe}{\box0}
 \begin{frame}\usebox{\thesaveframe}\end{frame}
}

\newcommand\savedframe[1]{\fboxsep=0pt%
  \fbox{\scalebox{#1}{\hspace{1cm}\usebox{\thesaveframe}\hspace{1cm}}}%
}
\begin{document}
%SAVE-FRAME AND OUTPUT IT
\begin{sframe}{1st Frame}
frame text from the first frame.  I will now begin an itemized list.  And we begin:
\begin{itemize}
\item AAA
\item BBB
\item CCC
\end{itemize}
\end{sframe}

%PRESENT THE 2ND FRAME INCLUDING A SCALED SAVE-FRAME
\begin{frame}
{2nd frame}
Here is my prior frame\par
\savedframe{.6}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if the frame I want to include contains animations? How can I include the very last slide, which has all the animations unfolded?

Comment: @Jessy09 I wish I could offer advice, but I have no experience with animations.  Perhaps you should ask it as a new question, so other eyes can see it.

Comment: I just did that. Thank you anyways for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

I needed this today as well, and I expanded a bit on Steven's answer, defining two commands which allow you to save and use immediately multiple frames and then reuse them later:

```
% \saveuseframe{id}{...} saves a frame to \saveid and uses it immediately, to be reused with \reuseframe{id}
\newcommand{\saveuseframe}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newsavebox\csname save#1\endcsname%
  \expandafter\savebox\csname save#1\endcsname{\vbox{\vspace{-.1em}#2}}%
  \begin{frame}\expandafter\usebox\csname save#1\endcsname\end{frame}}
\newcommand{\reuseframe}[1]{\fbox{\scalebox{.25}{\hspace{.9cm}\expandafter\usebox\csname save#1\endcsname\hspace{.8cm}}}}
```

This allows you to do this:

```
\savedframe{motivation}{\begin{frame}{Motivation}
  why?
\end{frame}}

... more stuff ...

\savedframe{future}{\begin{frame}{Future work}
  future stuff
\end{frame}}

\begin{frame}{Thank you!}
  \reuseframe{motivation}
  \reuseframe{future}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the special case the the previous frame should be inserted again, one can use the `\insertslideintonotes{<scale>}` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\edef\beamer@origlmargin{\Gm@lmargin}%
\edef\beamer@origrmargin{\Gm@rmargin}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
normal frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\insertslideintonotes{0.3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

If the frame in question should be saved for later reuse, one could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\edef\beamer@origlmargin{\Gm@lmargin}%
\edef\beamer@origrmargin{\Gm@rmargin}%
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
interesting frame
\end{frame}
\savebox{\mybox}{\insertslideintonotes{0.3}}

\begin{frame}
some other stuff
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\usebox{\mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```