# Beamer: Reuse Slides from same Presentation for Summary Slide

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am working on a presentation using the `beamer` package and I am wondering, whether there is a easy way to reuse images of single slides for a summary slide.
Up to now, I make a PDF print from each of the relevant slides, I want to use in the summary (named `summary-1` to `summary-4` in the MWE).
Afterwards, I include each of these printed PDFs for the summary slide.

Besides the MWE, I provide a screenshot of the last two overlays below and also the [PDF of the MWE](https://download.lukasczyk.me/summary-slides.pdf) for download.
Note that compilation of the full MWE is only possible after creating the images from the first four slides.
I am fully aware of this, it is the reason, why I ask this question.

Is there a way to avoid making PDFs from the single slides I want to use?
Obviously, this can be forgotten if it has to be done manually, which results in outdated slides in the summary.
Personally, I like this type of summary very much, as it gives a nice overview over the talk and eases the Q&A afterwards.

```
\documentclass[t,english,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First Topic}
  Slide on first topic}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second Topic}
  Slide on second topic}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Third Topic}
  Slide on third topic}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Fourth Topic}
  Slide on fourth topic}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Summary}
  \begin{textblock}{0}(0.2,1.3)
    \includegraphics<2->[width=7cm]{summary-1}
  \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{0}(8.0,1.3)
    \includegraphics<3->[width=7cm]{summary-2}
  \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{0}(0.2,8.3)
    \includegraphics<4->[width=7cm]{summary-3}
  \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{0}(8.0,8.3)
    \includegraphics<5->[width=7cm]{summary-4}
  \end{textblock}

  \begin{textblock}{0}(1.8,1.5)
    \includegraphics<1-1>[width=12.5cm]{summary-1}
    \includegraphics<2-2>[width=12.5cm]{summary-2}
    \includegraphics<3-3>[width=12.5cm]{summary-3}
    \includegraphics<4-4>[width=12.5cm]{summary-4}
  \end{textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot from final slides]

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207969/snapshot-like-macro-for-entire-beamer-frame and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69991/thumbnails-of-other-frames-in-beamer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step of making individual pdfs can be avoided. If you have a copy of your presentation, you can simply specify the page number.

```
\documentclass[t,english,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First Topic}
  Slide on first topic
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second Topic}
  Slide on second topic
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Third Topic}
  Slide on third topic
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Fourth Topic}
  Slide on fourth topic
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Summary}
  \begin{textblock}{0}(0.2,1.3)
    \includegraphics<2->[width=7cm,page=1]{summary}
  \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{0}(8.0,1.3)
    \includegraphics<3->[width=7cm,page=2]{summary}
  \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{0}(0.2,8.3)
    \includegraphics<4->[width=7cm,page=3]{summary}
  \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{0}(8.0,8.3)
    \includegraphics<5->[width=7cm,page=4]{summary}
  \end{textblock}

  \begin{textblock}{0}(1.8,1.5)
    \includegraphics<1-1>[width=12.5cm,page=1]{summary}
    \includegraphics<2-2>[width=12.5cm,page=2]{summary}
    \includegraphics<3-3>[width=12.5cm,page=3]{summary}
    \includegraphics<4-4>[width=12.5cm,page=4]{summary}
  \end{textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this needs me to keep a copy up-to-date, which is less work and less errorprone but still somehow annoying. Do you know a fully automatic solution, which does not require me to do anything manually, except calling `pdflatex` more than once?

Comment: Ah, I missed your other comment, thank you for that; I'll dig into that and maybe come back, if it does not help.

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk Copying the previous pdf before compiling can easily be done. Either via shell-escape, make files or an automation tool like arara.

Comment: Yes, that's right, shell-escape should be my way to go, to make it independent of a build tool. Thank you very much for this hint!

Answer (score 0):

We can do even better by using references for the pdf page numbers:

```latex
\documentclass[t,english,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{First Topic}
    \label{summary1}
    Slide on first topic
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Second Topic}
    \label{summary2}
    Slide on second topic
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Third Topic}
    \label{summary3}
    Slide on third topic
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Fourth Topic}
    \label{summary4}
    Slide on fourth topic
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[standout]{Summary}
    \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \def\width{6.5cm}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \includegraphics[width=\width,page=\getpagerefnumber{summary1}]{tmp_summary}&\includegraphics[width=\width,page=\getpagerefnumber{summary2}]{tmp_summary}\\
      \includegraphics[width=\width,page=\getpagerefnumber{summary3}]{tmp_summary}&\includegraphics[width=\width,page=\getpagerefnumber{summary4}]{tmp_summary}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```