# Snapshot for entire beamer frame with animations

Tags: beamer, animations

I would like to create a presentation where the last frame contains a summary of the whole presentation in the form of snapshots of the previous frames. Something similar has been asked and answered here: [Snapshot like macro for entire beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207969/snapshot-like-macro-for-entire-beamer-frame).

However, the frames I want to include as snapshots also contain animations and if I use the answer from that question, then a series of slides are included, as the animations unfold. Is there a way to take a snapshot of only the last slide, which has all the animations unfolded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479702/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\edef\beamer@origlmargin{\Gm@lmargin}%
\edef\beamer@origrmargin{\Gm@rmargin}%
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item AAA
\item BBB
\item CCC
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\savebox{\mybox}{\insertslideintonotes{0.3}}

\begin{frame}
some other stuff
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\usebox{\mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```