# Keeping zoomed out version of previous slide in present slide

Tags: beamer, zooming

I am making a beamer presentation. In some presentations, I have seen that a miniature version of previous slide is shown in present slide. This is very helpful to explain a complex definition. How do we achieve that? I tried putting content of previous slide in a column but it gets too crowdy.

Comment: [Snapshot like macro for entire beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479702/134144) should be useful.